# RDLC Page size using GetDefaultPageSettings

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have designed a report with the following sizes:

The report body size is as follows 9.86657in, 7.04374in
The report size is as follows

- InteractiveSize=w:11.69in, h:8.27in
- Margins=0.3in, 0.3in, 0.3in, 0.3in
- PageSize=w:11.69in, h:8.27in

When I load the report in C# and try to get the pagesizes using GetDefaultPageSettings why is it set to w=8.27in and h=11.69in???????

Does anyone know?  PLEASE HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms **10.0.0.0**` you can use the `GetDefaultPageSettings.IsLandscape` property.

If True you have to manually swap height/width before passing these value to your print function (`PrintDocument`, I suppose?).

Comment: The problem is that the width and height have been swapped around. How do I get the correct pagesizes?